# Prove that the following sequences monotonically decrease and increase correspondingly. Since they are bounded, find the limit.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, poisson-distribution

Let $\xi_n$ be a Poisson random variable with $\lambda = n \in \mathbb{N}$. That is $P(\xi_n = k) = \frac{n^ke^{-n}}{k!}$, for $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Let $f_+(n) = P(\xi_n \geq n),\ f_-(n) = P(\xi_n > n)$. Show that $f_+(n)$ monotonically decreases and $f_-(n)$ monotonically increases.

I have no idea how to prove this, I've tried mathematical induction and it didn't make any sense.

All what I've succeeded in is that $f_+(n) = f_-(n) + \frac{n^n e^{-n}}{n!}$. Last term here approaches $0$ when $n$ approaches infinity, what means that the limit of these two will be the same.

Comment: It might be of interest to use the fact that $\xi_n$ is (in law) the sum of $n$ iid Poisson rvs with parameter 1. Then, you have a recurrence build into the definition, that might help.

Comment: See  Henry Teicher. "An Inequality on Poisson Probabilities." Ann. Math. Statist. 26 (1) 147 - 149, March, 1955. https://doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177728608

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: There is unfortunately a major problem as pointed out by @Davide Giraudo in the comments. For the moment, I'll leave the answer up in the hope that it can be fixed.**

I have not found an easy way to get there, but here is my approach. First, take $X_i$ to be iid Poisson with parameter 1, so that we may take $\xi_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Next, we may write
\begin{align*}
f_+(n+1) &= \mathbb{P}\left(X_{n+1} \geq n+1 - \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} \geq n+1 - k)\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = k\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \geq n+1\right)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{e}\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{1}{(n+1-k)!}\cdot \dfrac{e^{-n}n^k}{k!} + f_+(n) - \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = n\right)\\
&= f_+(n) + \dfrac{1}{e}\cdot \dfrac{e^{-n}}{(n+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+1}{k}n^j - \dfrac{e^{-n}n^n}{n!}\\
&= f_+(n) + \dfrac{e^{-n}}{e(n+1)!}\left( (n+1)^{n+1} - n^{n+1} - en^n(n+1)\right).
\end{align*}
In particular $f_+$ is decreasing if the last term in parentheses is negative.
Set
$$
g(x) := \dfrac{(x+1)^{x+1}}{x^x(x + e(x+1))}
$$
for $x > 0$ and compute (e.g. with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=differentiate++%28x%2B1%29%5E%28x%2B1%29+%2F%28x%5E%28x%2B1%29+%2B+e*x%5Ex+*+%28x%2B1%29%29) if your are as lazy as I am)
$$
g'(x) = -\dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{x} + 1\right)^x (x + 1) \cdot \Big((e x + x + e) \ln\left(\frac{x}{x + 1}\right) + e + 1\Big)}{(e x + x + e)^2}.
$$
Next, we dtermine the sign of $g'$ by first nothing that, except for the last parenthesis in the nominator, everything is strictly positive, so that it suffices to note that
$$
h: x\mapsto (e x + x + e) \ln\left(\frac{x}{x + 1}\right) + e + 1
$$
is a non-decreasing function (as a sum and product of non-decreasing functions).
Now, as $x\to+\infty$, we have
$$
h(x) \approx e\ln(0) + (1+e)\ln\left(\left(1 - \frac{1}{x+1}\right)^{x}\right) + 1 + e \approx (1+e)\ln\left(e^{-1}\right) + (1+e) = 0,
$$
so that we can conclude that $h(x) \leq 0$ for all $x\geq 0$. This in turn means that $g'(x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$ and therefore $g$ is non-decreasing. Again, we take a look at the limit for $x\to+\infty$ of
$$
g(x) = \left(1 + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^x\cdot \dfrac{1 + x}{(1 + e)x + e} \approx e\cdot \dfrac{1}{1+e}.
$$
With this, we may conclude that
$$
g(x) \leq \dfrac{e}{1+e} < 1,
$$
which concludes the (extremely involved) argument.

I guess that a similar argument shows that $f_-$ is increasing, but I am not motivated enough to try it out. Also, I hope that there is an easier solution, because this is not very elegant ^^.

Comment: How do you go from $ \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} \geq n+1 - k)\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = k\right)$ to $\dfrac{1}{e}\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{1}{(n+1-k)!}\cdot \dfrac{e^{-n}n^k}{k!}$? I would have understood if it was $ \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = n+1 - k)$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo your are entirely right... I have tried to fix it, but couldn't find a good enough argument. I added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $Y_{\lambda}$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda>0$, then for each $n$,

$$
\tag{*}
\mathbb P(Y_\lambda\leqslant n)=\int_{\lambda}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}e^{-t}dt.
$$
This can be shown for instance by induction on $n$, where the induction step can be done via an integration by part.
Letting $a_n:=1-f_+(n)=\mathbb P(\xi_n\leqslant n-1)$  and $b_n:=1-f_-(n)=\mathbb P(\xi_n\leqslant n)$, we will show that $(a_n)$ is increasing and $(b_n)$ is decreasing.
Using (*), we find that
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}-a_n&=\mathbb P(\xi_{n+1}\leqslant n)-\mathbb P(\xi_n\leqslant n-1)\\
&=\int_{n+1}^\infty\frac{t^{n}}{n!}e^{-t}dt-\int_{n}^\infty\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-t}dt\\
&=\int_{n+1}^\infty\frac{t^{n}}{n!}e^{-t}dt-\left(\left[\frac{t^{n}}{n!}e^{-t}\right]_{t=n}^\infty-\int_n^\infty\frac{t^{n}}{n!}(-e^{-t})dt\right)\\
&=\int_{n+1}^\infty\frac{t^{n}}{n!}e^{-t}dt+\frac{n^{n}}{n!}e^{-n}-\int_n^\infty\frac{t^{n}}{n!} e^{-t} dt\\
&=\frac{n^{n}}{n!}e^{-n}-\int_n^{n+1}\frac{t^{n}}{n!} e^{-t}dt.
\end{align}
Doing the substitution $s=t-n$ reduces us to show that
$$
1>\int_0^1\left(1+\frac{s}n\right)^ne^{-s}ds,
$$
which follows from $\ln(1+u)< u$ for $u>0$.

By similar considerations, we find that the sign of $b_{n+1}-b_n$ is the same as that of
$$
1-\int_0^1\left(1+\frac{s}n\right)^{n+1}e^{-s}ds
$$
and having a look at the function $g\colon s\mapsto (n+1)\ln(1+s/n)-s$ gives what we want.

Notice that $\xi_n$ has the same distribution as $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $(X_i)$ is an i.i.d. sequence and $X_i$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter one. By the central limit theorem, we find that the limit of $f_+(n)$ and of $(f_-(n))$ is $1/2$.